# Grid functionality not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

I want to create a grid in jquery mobile for creating a calender. But instead of getting rows and coloumn arrangement i am getting only different rows and not coloumns. Please help

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>jQM Complex Demo</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>    
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="index">
        <div data-role="header"></div>

        <div data-role="content">
            <fieldset class="container_12" >
                <div class="ui-block-a"><div class="grid_2">day 1</div></div>
                <div class="ui-block-b"><div class="grid_2">day 2</div></div>      
                <div class="ui-block-c"><div class="grid_2">day 3</div></div>      
                <div class="ui-block-d"><div class="grid_2">day 4</div></div>
                <div class="ui-block-d"><div class="grid_2">day 5</div></div>
                <div class="ui-block-d"><div class="grid_2">day 6</div></div>


            </fieldset>
        </div>

        <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">

        </div>
    </div>   
</body>
</html>
```

The output is coming in this way rather than coming in grid form:

day 1
day 2
day 3
day 4
day 5 
day 6

This output is just an illustration of the recieved output and similar to the actual result

Comment: Shouldn't you be also loading the jquery library too?

Comment: Also don't know if jquery mobile 1.2.0 supports grid. Check the latest stable version here http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/grids/

Comment: how to add the jquery library needed?

Comment: just add `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>` before jQM `<script>` but you really should upgrade to jQM 1.4.5